# How to check the frequency bands of 3G and LTE carriers to make sure they are supported by iPhone 4s, 5, 5s, 5c?

Tags: iphone

Suppose you am living outside US & you want to buy iphone like 4s,5, 5s,5c in US.

Then How can you check the frequency bands of 3G and 4G LTE carriers (in the place u r living) to make sure they are supported by iPhone 4s, 5, 5s, 5c?

So, Each carrier use just 1 band right? or

is there any carrier that require your iPhone to suppose 2 bands?

also, are there 2 or more carriers that use the same band?

Quite confused.

Answer (score 1):

One place would be to look on Apple's [own page here](http://www.apple.com/iphone/LTE/).

There is way too much detail on that page for me to summarise here, but it covers most (all?) countries and carriers where the iPhone is currently available, including those in the US.

So find any models that are supported by your current (non-US) carrier, and see whether those models work with any US carriers.

Comment: but it is still not very clear cos I don't know which specific Band a carrier in charge. For example, regarding 4G LTE, each carrier will have 1 band only or they have many bands

Comment: For that, you would need to find out from the carriers. They may tell you on their own website, or you may be able to find out from forums on the internet.

Comment: Actually, you don't care which band the carrier uses - you only care which models of iPhone support that carrier, and that information is available on the link I included.

Comment: But a carrier may have many different services. For ex, u r using 4G WiMax in Sprint & iPhone does not support WiMax . However u read somewhere people saying that this iPhone model is supported in Sprint but actually for different network not for WiMax. So it is still very important to know it in details.

Comment: I didn't say it was easy! And it's all country- and carrier-specific, so I am afraid you are going to have to do some research ...

Comment: yes, i am doing research for my company